# $f(x)= (x^2-1)^\frac{2}{3}$ on $[-3,3]$ applying Fermat's Theorem using closed interval method.

Tags: calculus, derivatives

> $f(x)= (x^2-1)^\frac{2}{3}$ on $[-3,3]$ With Closed interval method

I learned that the Fermat Theorem states that suppose $f(x)$ has a local extremal at $x=c$, and $f'(c)$ exist, then $f'(c)=0$ and $f'(c)$ does not exists if $x=c$ is a "singular" point.

So, using the closed interval method, the largest and smallest value of $f(x)$ is the maximum and minimum value in the interval $[a,b]$ respectively.

So, for example, for $f(t)= (t)^\frac{3}{2} (8-t)$, this graph only has 1 extremal point, so I can set $f'(t)=0$

But for the question I asked about, $f(x)= (x^2-1)^\frac{2}{3}$ on $[-3,3]$, checking the how the graph looks like, it has more than 1 extremal point.

Setting, $f'(x)=0$, $x=0$ and this is the critical point. However, my teacher said during lessons that we have to consider $x=1$ and $x=-1$ too which are the "singular" points I mentioned above. How do I know whether do I need to check "singular" points without checking the shape of the graph?

Comment: You are supposed to know the usual functions and where there are differentiable or not. Here the cube root function is not differentiable at $0$ and therefore the function $(x^2-1)^\frac{2}{3}$ is not differentiable for $x=1$ or $x=-1$ (and you could see it easily since the derivative is diverging at those points) .

Comment: You should know the rules for finding the derivatives of powers, sums, and constants, and you should know the chain rule. Those are sufficient for calculating the derivative of this function. Where does that derivative fail to exist?